# How to force a FilerImageField to convert image format

Tags: django

I'm trying to force certain `FilerImageFields` to be convert to another format on saving.

I've created this model

```
class SearchImage(FilerImageField):
    def convert_to_webp(self):
        print("in convert")
        extension = ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'img', 'gif']
        if any(ext in self.file.name.lower() for ext in extension):

            #try:
                img = Image.open(self.file)
                correggi_nome = self.file.name.split('.')[0]
                img.save(correggi_nome + '.webp','webp')
                logger.debug('img.save save another copy of the file not repalced the original!')

            #except Exception as ex:
            #    logger.error(ex)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.convert_to_webp()
        print("Save search image")
        super().save()

class Organisation(models.Model):
    ....
    search_image = SearchImage(
        related_name='+',
        verbose_name=_('Search thumbnail image'),
        help_text=_('Search thumbnail image'),
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    ....
    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        print('saving')
        print("just before search thumbnail save")
        self.search_image.save()        
        print("just after search thumbnail save")
        super.save()
```

my `SeachImage.save()` is never called.  When I save an image (or organisation) I see the print statements within the Organisation.save() but not the SearchImage.save().  How to I get this to work?

Comment: Just to be clear, is `print("just after search thumbnail save")` called?

Comment: yes, but not the print within the `SearchImage.save()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I went down a bit of a rabbit hole but it looks like you want to overwrite the Image object's save method, not the FilerImageField, which is a ForeignKey object:

```py
class MyImageModel(Image):
    def convert_to_webp(self):
        print('in convert')
        extension = ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'img', 'gif']
        if any(ext in self.file.name.lower() for ext in extension):
            print('Doing the conversion')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.convert_to_webp()
        print('Save search image')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class SearchImage(FilerImageField):
    default_model_class = MyImageModel


class Organisation(models.Model):
    search_image = FilerImageField(
        verbose_name='Search thumbnail image',
        help_text='Search thumbnail image',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.search_image.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```